# Does there exist a definition of equivalence of functors?

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory

I have two functors $F_1,F_2$ from a category $C$ into two distinct categories $D_1,D_2$. I would like to say that $F_1$ and $F_2$ are equivalent if there exists a commutative square
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
C @>F_1>> D_1\\
@V F_2 V V @VV E_1 V\\
D_2 @>>E_2> D
\end{CD}
of functors such that the $E_i$ are equivalences. Can one say that this notion is well-known?:) Do there exist any similar notions in the literature?

Upd. Possibly, it would be better to reverse the arrows here, that is, to demand that there exists a functor $F$ (that is bijective on objects) and two equivalences of categories $E_1$ and $E_2$ such that $F_i=E_i\circ F$.

Comment: I think this is a special case of $F_1$ and $F_2$ being equivalent in an appropriate weak arrow 2-category of $\mathbf{Cat}$, where the morphisms are squares commuting up to isomorphism. But if you want this specific notion I can't say that I've seen it.

Comment: yes, see https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/slice+2-category (or rather coslice 2-category)

Comment: @DanPetersen: It seems like that’s essentially a complete answer — would you make it one? :-)

Comment: You can use $E_1^{-1} E_2$ to simplify the square to a triangle (which commutes up to iso).

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg. No: equivalences need not have inverses (without the violence of the axiom of choice). $E_1$ and $E_2$ could be equivalences in the sense of being full, faithful and essentially surjective. It is not difficult to show that  zig-zags like this can be reduced to spans.

Comment: I work with ZFC + universes, so equivalences have pseudo-inverses. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: Do you never "work with" *internal* categories in categories of spaces, schemes or sheaves? The natural setting for this question is in a category with (some) finite limits. By all means use ZFC++ if you're in the heat of battle with a tricky theorem and troublesome counterexamples, but don't use Choice to make trivial "simplifications" of already simple fundamental ideas when these simplifications actually mislead about what's going on.

Comment: Yes I work with internal categories, but the question was not about them. When I comment here, I refer to the OP's question and not some much more general implicit context. If you want to do that, that's fine. What I said is true for the standard definition of an equivalence of categories ( = a functor with a pseudo-inverse). But even when we talk about internal categories, I wonder if you really want to say that "fully faithful and essentially surjective" is the correct definition of an equivalence?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Yes, I believe that's the standard definition, much as one uses weak equivalences of arbitrary spaces and simplicial sets moreso than homotopy equivalences.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: The formula "fully faithful and essentially surjective" is the beginning of the story, not the end. For internal categories in, say, a category of spaces (or locales), "surjective" could be an "open (or proper) surjection". You then have to control what finite limits you're using. In HoTT they have another notion of equivalence, that the fibres are contractible. Assuming Choice (epis split) in your ambient category just destroys the fun.

Answer (score 8):

It's worth first understanding the 1-categorical analogue: what would it mean for two arrows $f \colon X \to Y$ and $f' \colon X \to Y'$ in a category $C$, which share the same domain, to be isomorphic? One way of making sense of this is by saying that they are isomorphic in the *coslice category* $X/C$, whose objects are pairs $(Y,f)$ where $Y$ is an object of $C$ and $f \colon X \to Y$ is an arrow; morphisms are commutative triangles.

Your question is really about the analogue of the above when $C$ is not a 1-category but the 2-category $Cat$. Now there are multiple inequivalent ways of defining a "coslice 2-category" under an object of a 2-category, depending on whether you want the 2-morphisms to be invertible, or identities, or if they are not invertible, in which case you need to choose a direction for them. You want invertible 2-cells, which is also what people will generally expect by default if you only say "coslice 2-category". More precisely, the following are equivalent:

1. there exists a square as in your question which commutes strictly
2. there exists a square as in your question which commutes up to a natural isomorphism
3. there exists a commuting triangle which commutes up to a natural isomorphism

However, asking for a triangle which commutes strictly is in general strictly stronger (and seems like a rather unnatural notion).

https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/slice+2-category

Comment: My impression is that it doesn't make sense to weaken the commutativity condition for my square.

Comment: @MikhailBondarko (Provided I am not mistaken) if you do not weaken this condition your notion is not going to be isomorphism invariant. That is, there might be cases when $F_1$ is equivalent to $F_2$, $F_1$ is isomorphic to $F_1'$ and $F_1'$ is not equivalent to $F_2$, no?

Comment: I suspect that this is impossible - but I didn't check this.

Comment: Your comments about triangles are interesting.  What is their relationship to  @MartinBrandenburg's comment and my response to it?

Comment: @Paul Sorry, which are the above statements you mean?

Comment: @PaulTaylor What I wrote in the comment above precisely makes the connection to slice categories mentioned by others here (in slice categories, morphisms are triangles). This is what I wanted to clarify.